# Support Vector Machine classifier error

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm

I don't understand why when i run tune.svm and then i run summary, i have only this result:

> Error estimation of ‘svm’ using 10-fold cross-validation: 0.01385764, whereas I expect also best parameters etc..

I tried this:

```
tuned <- tune.svm(y~.,
                  data = training,
                  gamma = 10^-2, cost = 10^2,
                  tunecontrol = tune.control(cross = 10))

summary(tuned)
#> Error estimation of ‘svm’ using 10-fold cross validation: 0.01385764
```

and this:

```
set.seed(222)
tunesvm <- tune(svm, y ~ ., data = training, kernel = "sigmoid",
                ranges = list(cost = 0.001)
plot(tunesvm)
summary(tunesvm)
#> Error estimation of ‘svm’ using 10-fold cross validation: 0.01788785
```

Comment: This in no way answers the question, but it's a "support vector machine" rather than a super vector machine. Though I might use that for a song name :-)

Comment: 1. What package is `tune.svm` in?  It would help if you include the `library` statement in your question.  . 2 . Have you tried `str(tuned)` ?

Comment: library(e1071)@G5W

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is caused by the fact you already specify one value per hyper parameter. What best parameters do you expect when there are one of each to choose from?

To get the best parameters you must specify a sequence of values for the hyper parameters from which the CV will choose the best combination by a grid search.

Here is a full example:

```
library(mlbench)
library(e1071)

data(Sonar)
set.seed(222)
tuned <- tune.svm(Class~.,
                  data = Sonar,
                  gamma = 10^(-1:-3), cost = 10^(1:3), ,
                  tunecontrol = tune.control(cross = 10))

summary(tuned)
#output:

Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:

- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 

- best parameters:
 gamma cost
  0.01   10

- best performance: 0.1247619 

- Detailed performance results:
  gamma cost     error dispersion
1 0.100   10 0.2064286 0.08641724
2 0.010   10 0.1247619 0.07165924
3 0.001   10 0.2359524 0.08655125
4 0.100  100 0.2064286 0.08641724
5 0.010  100 0.1247619 0.07165924
6 0.001  100 0.2209524 0.09521693
7 0.100 1000 0.2064286 0.08641724
8 0.010 1000 0.1247619 0.07165924
9 0.001 1000 0.1823810 0.10762794

 plot(tuned)
```

[image]

Comment: tnks, now works@missuse